# Can I use a junction box on a 30 amps 240 V circuit?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I want to move my electric dryer. The circuit is 240v 30 amps. Am I allowed to use a junction box (leaving it accessible)? The aim is to not have to redo the complete run of cable. Wire is 10-3 (Black, Red, White, Bare).

Location is Quebec, Canada.

Comment: I think you are, it is nicer if you don't need to, but if needed it should be allowed if the splices are done right/correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The junction box is simply the method. Your question is "Can I extend my dryer circuit?"

**The issue with dryers is grounding.**  *Many* dryer circuits were installed with 3-wire 10/3 **with no ground** (black white red) and some were illegally installed with 2-wire 10/2+ground (black white bare).

Those dryer circuits cannot be extended because they lack a ground wire, which is true of any circuit extension.

To be clear, dryers require neutral.  The 3rd wire is neutral not ground,, and if ground is present, it must be separate from neutral.

As long as the existing dryer connection is 4-wire, or is 3-wire with insulated neutral and solid metal conduit back to the panel, then it may be extended. Use a junction box extension, or a surface conduit system like Legrand Wiremold.

Comment: ground is good, but thanks for pointing out

Comment: @Jeffrey as long as it is separate from neutral. Both must be independent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course. All the usual rules for junctions and splices are in play. The box needs to be of an adequate size and type, the box must be readily accessible, the type of splice must be correct and of the correct sized wire and type, etc etc.

But there is nothing in particular that is wrong with having a junction box for a 30A 240V circuit.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. About the only time you can't (practically speaking) use a junction box is for the ground wire from the main panel to the ground rod and/or water pipe. From a practical standpoint, junctions on really big wire (e.g., 100A for a big subpanel) are a bit more of a problem because you can't use cheap little wire nuts. But for 30A, no problem at all.